# How to add time to Date Picker

Tags: swift

I am totaly new in swift and I need your help. 
I would like to add 6 hours to the Date Picker (to the time which I have selected in Date picker).

1. Select Time in Date Picker (14:00)
2. Plus 6 Hours (14:00 + 6:00)
3. Print in Label the result (20:00)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use calendar:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 6, to: selectedDateByPicker)
```

> Print in Label the result (20:00)

```
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH-mm"
print(dateformatter.string(from: date));
```

Comment: Thx a lot, Now I would like to add another Date Picker and use it for "overtime". On second date picker you choose for example (1hod 20min, 1:20) and subtract it from first Date picker. Am I able to use two date pickers and subtract time from them? I mean I know that I can ged difference but this is something else. 

The result should be, time when you can leave the office.

Comment: if you only want to add or subtract some value from the a date object, use my above described way. But if you want to subtract one date from other and only want to know the difference, then do in this way. let diff = date1.timeIntervalSince1970 - date1.timeIntervalSince1970;  this difference will be in seconds among to date objects.